# What is the PCI compliance level for the BlueSnap Payment API? How do I limit PCI requirements for BlueSnap Payment API?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, pci-compliance, bluesnap

- I am using the BlueSnap Payment API and wondering what PCI scope does
  my application fall under?
- How do I limit PCI requirements for BlueSnap Payment API?

Answer (score 2):

For point# 1- It depends. The BlueSnap API allows various ways to integrate. The following link has a summary of PCI scope with for the different API usage: http://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/pci-compliance

For point # 2 - To reduce the burden of PCI, BlueSnap supports Client Side Encryption which will give you SAQ A-EP scope and Hosted Payment Fields which will give you SAQ A. Information on how to implement these integration methods can be found here: http://developers.bluesnap.com/v4.0/docs/hosted-payment-fields and here: http://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/client-side-encryption